# How to save an existing file from C#

Tags: c#

I want to save an existing text file from C#. I don’t want to write or add anything, just save the file.

Please help.

I just want to save an existing text file from c#. I want this to happen for one of Unity projects.

Comment: `want to save an existing text file` where you want to save? If file is already exist it already saved. What different saving you want to do? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Did you mean that you want to overwrite an existing file? What is your goal? Please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use one of the static [`WriteXY` methods in the `File` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-7.0#methods).

Comment: I want to save a text file inside a Unity update function, which means when I overwrite the file from outside it will get saved from Unity in each update frame.